# How to give ranking to content?

Tags: views

I have created a content type named **Ranking** and also created a field ***rank this content***. If I give rank 1,2,3 and so on.

Content should display according to rank, the content with rank 1 should show at first position and so on.

Any idea how to perform this?

**Note**: I'm using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: A note for others who find this one (as its an old post) and are aiming to achieve something similar - one option would be to derive a Ranking from Ratings (noting that these are of course two different things) using https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi and either https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar or https://www.drupal.org/project/rate.

It may also be possible to derive a ranking from the outcomes generated by a voteup/downvote modules, but I have not tested this out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by following below steps.

1. Create view of **Ranking** content type.
2. Add fields you want to show to your listing.
3. Now add sort criteria of field **rank this content** with selecting **Ascending** operation.

Comment: It should be there, try searching rank keyword.

Comment: in sort criteria there are so many fields including ** "Indexed Node: rank this content"** not showing :(

Comment: search for "rank this content". You are using views?

Comment: No Sssweat @ya using views

Comment: thanks there was problem with search api after reindexing  
"rank this content field"is showing

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module as suggested in the prior answer.

However, to ***give ranking to content*** (as in your title), you could take this a step further. I.e. to automate the calculation of your "rank this content" field, by using the [Radioactivity](https://www.drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module. Some details about this module (from its project page):

> ... provides a field type which can be used as a hotness metric or a regular view counter for entities and for much much more. In essense, entities receiving attention (views or actions defined by Rules) are heated while inactive ones slowly cool down.

Refer to the article "[Radioactivity 2: basics](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/radioactivity-2-basics/2011-12-05)" for way more details / ideas about this very interesting module ...